# How do I switch the appearance of a button onClick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, toggle

I have created a button: '.switch' , which switches between two divs '.gi' and '.nogi' - this works well, but what I cannot seem to get working is for the .switch appearance itself to change upon clicking.

I've tried functions using toggle and toggleClass, neither of which work for me yet.

the page is live on https://www.novagrappling.com/rules.html

You will notice there are two buttons, one with GI highlighted in red, the other with NOGI highlighted. Ideally I wanted Gi highlighted initially, with NOGI hidden, which switches onClick along with the div underneath.
Thanks

```js
$('div.nogi, div.switched').hide();
$(".switch").on("click", function() {
  $('div.gi, div.nogi').toggle();
  $('div.switch, div.switched').toggle();
});
```

```css
.switch,
.switched {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
}

.gi-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #cd3046;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gi-switched {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #232528;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nogi-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #232528;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nogi-switched {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #cd3046;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a class="switch">
  <div class="gi-switch">
    <div class="gi-title">GI</div>
  </div>
  <div class="nogi-switch">
    <div class="nogi-title">NO GI</div>
  </div>
</a>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you add some html to the question?

Comment: Learn how the DOM API works before using libraries.

Comment: @ksav done, html added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `.toggleClass()` didn't work for you. You can use it like this:

```
$('.switch .gi-switch').toggleClass('gi-switched');
$('.switch .nogi-switch').toggleClass('nogi-switched');
```

If you add this to your onclick function, you should get something close to what you want.

```js
$('div.nogi').hide();
$(".switch").on("click", function() {
  $('div.gi, div.nogi').toggle();
  $('.switch .gi-switch').toggleClass('gi-switched');
  $('.switch .nogi-switch').toggleClass('nogi-switched');
});
```

```css
.switch,
.switched {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
}

.gi-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #cd3046;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gi-switched {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #232528;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nogi-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #232528;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nogi-switched {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #cd3046;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a class="switch">
  <div class="gi-switch">
    <div class="gi-title">GI</div>
  </div>
  <div class="nogi-switch">
    <div class="nogi-title">NO GI</div>
  </div>
</a>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for this, we're getting close. a new problem has arisen now where the .gi and .nogi doesn't toggle properly, check the live page

Comment: It appears to be toggling for me. What kind of behavior are you looking for?

Comment: its toggling, but '.switched' is visible the entire time, and .nogi doesn't display at all.

Comment: It appears that I accidentally copied `$('div.nogi, div.switched').hide();` from somewhere else and put it into the onClick method. Removing that should allow `div.nogi` to display

Comment: Also, the way I have it now does not require a second set of buttons that you had originally. It changes the class on the one set which, in turn, changes their colors. You can remove the second set of button switches and remove the parts that toggle `div.switched`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Its working for me now on the live site, please give it a double check to see if it works for you, thanks so much for your help Zach

Comment: Works for me! Glad I could help!